# Modify bound variables of a closure in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, closures

Is there any way to modify the bound value of one of the variables inside a closure? Look at the example to understand it better.

```
def foo():
    var_a = 2
    var_b = 3

    def _closure(x):
        return var_a + var_b + x

    return _closure


localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
# ...but what magic? Is this even possible?

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 +1 == 4
```

Comment: Possible in Python 3.7+; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55320884/4880003 or Brian Adams' answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do that in Python. When the closure is defined, the current state of variables in the enclosing scope is captured and no longer has a directly referenceable name (from outside the closure). If you were to call `foo()` again, the new closure would have a different set of variables from the enclosing scope.

In your simple example, you might be better off using a class:

```
class foo:
        def __init__(self):
                self.var_a = 2
                self.var_b = 3

        def __call__(self, x):
                return self.var_a + self.var_b + x

localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
# ...but what magic? Is this even possible?
localClosure.var_a = 0

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 +1 == 4
```

If you do use this technique I would no longer use the name `localClosure` because it is no longer actually a closure. However, it works the same as one.

Comment: +1: first-class object rather than closure.  Closure is a peculiar non-object thing.  Objects are clearer and easier to deal with than closures.

Comment: There is in fact a way.  nonlocal.  See my post.

Comment: for future readers, this became possible in 2017 with Python 3.7.0 alpha 1, see my post for details

Answer (score 57):

It is quite possible in python 3 thanks to the magic of [nonlocal](http://jeremyhylton.blogspot.com/2007/02/nonlocal-implemented.html).

```
def foo():
        var_a = 2
        var_b = 3

        def _closure(x, magic = None):
                nonlocal var_a
                if magic is not None:
                        var_a = magic

                return var_a + var_b + x

        return _closure


localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6
print(a)

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
localClosure(0, 0)

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 +1 == 4
print(b)
```

Comment: i would too, it's certainly better than the other way. i just meant that by default it should be nonlocal

Comment: Doh!  I meant to say I wouldn't.  It still looks weird and hacky to me.  The whole bit about the optional parameter to change value.  Whole thing should be a class.  But anyway, I digress.

Comment: for future readers, this became possible with no code changes required in 2017 with Python 3.7.0 alpha 1, see my post for details

Answer (score 12):

I've found an alternate answer answer to Greg's, slightly less verbose because it uses Python 2.1's custom function attributes (which conveniently enough can be accessed from inside their own function).

```
def foo():
    var_b = 3

    def _closure(x):
        return _closure.var_a + var_b + x

    _closure.func_dict['var_a'] = 2
    return _closure


localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
# ...but what magic? Is this even possible?
# apparently, it is
localClosure.var_a = 0

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 +1 == 4
```

Thought I'd post it for completeness. Cheers anyways.

Answer (score 11):

We've done the following.  I think it's simpler than other solutions here.

```
class State:
    pass

def foo():
    st = State()
    st.var_a = 2
    st.var_b = 3

    def _closure(x):
        return st.var_a + st.var_b + x
    def _set_a(a):
        st.var_a = a

    return _closure, _set_a


localClosure, localSetA = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
localSetA(0)

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 +1 == 4

print a, b
```

Answer (score 5):

I worked around a similar limitation by using one-item lists instead of a plain variable.  It's ugly but it works because modifying a list item doesn't get treated as a binding operation by the interpreter.

For example:

```
def my_function()
    max_value = [0]

    def callback (data)

        if (data.val > max_value[0]):
            max_value[0] = data.val

        # more code here
        # . . . 

    results = some_function (callback)

    store_max (max_value[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

### Question

> Is there any way to modify the bound value of one of the variables inside a closure?

### TLDR

Yes, this is possible starting in Python 3.7.0 alpha 1:

```py
localClosure.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 0
```

### Details

In Python, a closure remembers the variables from the scope in which it was defined by using a special `__closure__` attribute.  The `__closure__` attribute is a tuple of `cell` objects representing the variables from the outer scope, and the values of those variables are stored in the `cell_contents` attribute of each `cell`.

Given the code from the question, this can be seen by running the following:

```py
# print the list of cells
print(localClosure.__closure__)
# (<cell at 0x7f941ca27a00: int object at 0x7f941a621950>, <cell at 0x7f941ca27eb0: int object at 0x7f941a621970>)

# print the values in the cells
print(', '.join(str(cell.cell_contents) for cell in localClosure.__closure__))
# 2, 3

# print the value in the first cell (var_a)
print(localClosure.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
# 2
```

The `cell_contents` attribute of the `cell` objects first became writable with [bpo-30486](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74671) which was first included in [Python 3.7.0 alpha 1](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html?highlight=__closure__#python-3-7-0-alpha-1)

Complete working example:

```py
def foo():
    var_a = 2
    var_b = 3

    def _closure(x):
        return var_a + var_b + x

    return _closure


localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
# ...but what magic? Is this even possible?

# the magic
# this changes the value in the cell representing var_a to be 0
localClosure.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 0

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 + 1 == 4
```

Comment: I was excited that Python 3.7 had made this possible, until I read the details. I don't want to put this in my code or see it in anyone else's. It violates the expectation that the only direct access to a variable is through its name. And the expectation that the order of definition of variables shouldn't in general matter.

Comment: @nclark multiple Python core devs thought it was a reasonable thing to add so I'm sure there must be valid use cases that they considered, but yeah in general I agree that directly manipulating `__closure__` is something to avoid (unless you are doing something like "(un)pickling recursive closures" like was mentioned in the github issue)

Comment: Remark: it's possible to access the `var_a` by name I believe, refer to [closures - Reflect / Inspect closed-over variables in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416876/reflect-inspect-closed-over-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

slightly different from what was asked, but you could do:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    def g(x, a=a, b=b):
        return a + b + x
    return g

h = f()
print(h(0))
print(h(0,2,3))
print(h(0))
```

and make the closure the default, to be overridden when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a further approach (even if it seems to be some years too late for my proposal :-)

```
def foo():
    def _closure(x):
        return _closure.var_a + _closure.var_b + x
    _closure.var_a = 2
    _closure.var_b = 3
    return _closure


localClosure = foo()

# Local closure is now "return 2 + 3 + x"
a = localClosure(1)  # 2 + 3 + 1 == 6
print(a)

# DO SOME MAGIC HERE TO TURN "var_a" of the closure into 0
# ...but what magic? Is this even possible?
localClosure.var_a = 0

# Local closure is now "return 0 + 3 + x"
b = localClosure(1)  # 0 + 3 +1 == 4
print(b)
```

From my point of view the class solution proposed is easier to read. But if you try to modiy a free variable inside a decorator this solution might come in handy: In comparison to a class based solution it's easier to work with functools.wraps to preserve the meta data of the decorated function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make var_a and var_b arguments of the function foo?

```
def foo(var_a = 2, var_b = 3):
    def _closure(x):
        return var_a + var_b + x
    return _closure

localClosure = foo() # uses default arguments 2, 3
print localClosure(1) # 2 + 3 + 1 = 6

localClosure = foo(0, 3)
print localClosure(1) # 0 + 3 + 1 = 4
```

Comment: That's doesn't quite answer my problem, because I need to modify the values of closures which are already created. I.e. your answer requires me to create a new closure everytime I need to change the bound variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    var_a = 2
    var_b = 3

    def _closure(x):
            return var_a + var_b + x

    return _closure

def bar():
        var_a = [2]
        var_b = [3]

        def _closure(x):
                return var_a[0] + var_b[0] + x


        def _magic(y):
            var_a[0] = y

        return _closure, _magic

localClosureFoo = foo()
a = localClosureFoo(1)
print a



localClosureBar, localClosureBarMAGIC = bar()
b = localClosureBar(1)
print b
localClosureBarMAGIC(0)
b = localClosureBar(1)
print b
```