# Exec, closures and scopes

Tags: python, scope, closures

Let's say I want to implement an identity decorator with exec (ie, it shouldn't do absolutely nothing to a function without parameters). When I try to define a closure using that decorator, the scope survives the end of the f_factory function and changes what comes next.

I want to understand **why does the last print return "1b" and not "1"**.

```
def exec_identity(f):

    gl = globals()
    gl.update({'f':f})

    exec "def idfun(): return f()" in gl, locals()
    return idfun


class CallableClass(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def make_callable(self):
        def f_factory(s):
            def f():
                print s

            return exec_identity(f)
            #return f
        return f_factory(self.s)




c1 = CallableClass("1")
f1 = c1.make_callable()
f1()
c1.s = "1b"
f1()
f1b = c1.make_callable()
f1b()
f1()

"""
Result:

1
1
1b
1b
"""
```

I know that if I can leave the exec statement like this for it to work as expected:

```
exec "def idfun(): return f()" in {'f':f}, locals()
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392349/modify-bound-variables-of-a-closure-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that

```
gl = globals()
gl.update({'f':f})
```

in all cases works on the same object.

So the global `f()` is exchanged with a new one, and is called. The old one, along with its closure, gets lost.

```
gl = dict(globals())
gl.update({'f':f})
```

prevents that by copying the `globals()` dict.

Comment: @Zah Updated answer as well.

Comment: According to the docs:  "globals(): Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table." But apparently that doesn't mean it is a read only copy, but it also modifies the actual global symbols...

Comment: @Zah Right. The doc is ambiguous in this concern. "representing" might mean that it is already a copy, or taht it really returns the dicht the global symol table actually uses (the latter seems to be the case). As a normal `dict`, it cannot be read-only; so obviously you indeed modify the real globals.