# Scope of local variables in Python

Tags: python, scope

I changed the [DFS pseudocode for Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on Wiki for python and got the following:

```
def topological_sort(nodes):
    """Topological sort for DAGs. Written based on pseudocode on Wiki.
    DFS-based sort by Tarjan 1976"""        
    L=[]
    def visit(node):
        if node.dfs_tmark:
            print ("Error: Graph is not a DAG")
        if not node.dfs_pmark:
            node.dfs_tmark=True
            for m in node.parents:
                visit(m)
            node.dfs_pmark=True
            L=[node]+L
    for node in nodes:
        if not (node.dfs_pmark and node.dfs_tmark):
            visit(node)
```

However I am getting the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L' referenced before assignment`. As far as I remember python looks for variables backwards in scopes and I wonder why it cannot reach "L"?

Comment: Why not just make `L` an argument and not rely on scope at all?

Comment: You have to define L beforehand in order to concatenate here(L=[node]+L).

Comment: @iamsudip, well I already did. Just before visit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18002922/650884

Comment: @jonrsharpe, still the same error.

Comment: You cannot redefine L with `L=...`. Use `L.insert(0, node)` instead.

Comment: @Messa, why not? I actually did and it works.

Comment: @Pavel, thank you very much, I thought global makes a variable completely global! :)

Comment: @Cupitor it works? What was that `UnboundLocalError` then? :) Of course, you can redefine variable in Python, but if you want to use that variable as a bound variable in a closure, you cannot redefine that variable in the inner scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392349/modify-bound-variables-of-a-closure-in-python

Comment: @Messa, hehe! I meant you are objecting to redefining it! :)
I see! I actually used global statement. Maybe that one works as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read from variables which are defined in outer scope but you can't write into it without specifying the [global statement](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html). In your example it should work as soon as you specify `global L` in the first line of your visit method.

Comment: Except `L` is not a global, it is a `nonlocal`.

Comment: But the nonlocal-statement is available from Python3 and not for Python2… And as far as I remember the `global` statement should do the work right?

Comment: Well, it will make a *global* L, which will shadow the enclosing scope's `L`.

Comment: Yeah thats right… I only don't see a better solution (except avoiding globals / nonlocals completely) as long we don't all (or at least the threadstarter) use Python3… :/

Comment: It's very simple, don't use assignment.  `L+= [node]` or `L.append(node)` both work on python 2.