# How do I access/modify variables from a function's closure?

Tags: python, closures

If I have a function which has some non-local variable (in a closure), how do I access that variable? Can I modify it, and if so, how? Here's an example of such a function:

```py
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner(y):
        nonlocal x
        return x + y
    return inner

inner = outer()
# how do I get / change the value of x inside inner?
```

(apologies if this is already answered elsewhere; I couldn't find it, so I thought I would share the answer once I worked it out)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function's enclosed variables are stored as a tuple in the `__closure__` attribute. The variables are stored as a `cell` type, which seems to just be a mutable container for the variable itself. You can access the variable a `cell` stores as `cell.cell_contents`. Because cells are mutable, you can change the values of a function's non-local variables by changing the cell contents. Here's an example:

```py
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner(y):
        nonlocal x
        return x + y
    return inner

inner = outer()

print(inner(2))  # 3
print(inner.__closure__)  # (<cell at 0x7f14356caf78: int object at 0x56487ab30380>,)
print(inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents)  # 1

inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 10
print(inner(2))  # 12
print(inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents)  # 10
```

EDIT - the above answer applies to Python 3.7+. For other Python versions, you can access the closure the same way, but you **can't modify** the enclosed variables ([here's](https://bugs.python.org/issue30486) the Python issue that tracked setting cell values).

Comment: I get `AttributeError: attribute 'cell_contents' of 'cell' objects is not writable` with CPython 3.6.7. With pypy 6 I get `AttributeError: readonly attribute 'cell_contents'` What version on Python are you using that allows writing to `cell_contents`? Or do I have to configure something to make that work?

Comment: Ah, I didn't check any other versions; I was using 3.7 when I ran that. I'll update now.

Comment: Remark: it's possible to access the `x` by name I believe, refer to [closures - Reflect / Inspect closed-over variables in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416876/reflect-inspect-closed-over-variables-in-python)