# Understanding memoization in Python

Tags: python

I would like to understand memoization in Python better. In an online class I am taking, the following example is provided:

```
def memoize(func):
    memo_dict = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in memo_dict:
            memo_dict[args] = func(*args)
        return memo_dict[args]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def find_divisors_memo(n):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors
```

I am trying to find the numerical values stored in `memo_dict` after running a few examples, e.g.:

```
find_divisors_memo(100000009)
find_divisors_memo(100000008)
```

I do:

```
for x,y in memo_dict.items():      
        print(x,y)
```

and it says: `NameError: name 'memo_dict' is not defined`.

Comment: `memo_dict` isn't global, it's local to `memoize` and only available to `wrapper` via the *closure*.

Comment: Hello Bogdan, i suppose you are executing the for outside the function. The problem here is that the memo_dict = {} is local to the function and you can't call it from outside. If you'll put your for inside, it will work.

Comment: side note: if you want to use a function cache [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) is probably the best choice.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55320884/3001761 for how to access the closure contents. You can also make the dictionary an attribute on the `wrapper` function, so it's more easily accessible, like in [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268784/3001761).

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your help and comments. If you could please offer a more precise solution -- how shall I change the code. I am still learning a lot about python.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a look at the dict for the purpose of understanding memoization, you can add a few `print` statements:

```py
def memoize(func):
    memo_dict = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in memo_dict:
            memo_dict[args] = func(*args)
        else:
            print('using cached value')
        print(memo_dict.items())
        return memo_dict[args]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def find_divisors_memo(n):
    print('function called')
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors
```

Now you can see the items of the dict in every function call.
Also, you'll see how memoization works: If you call the function with a specific parameter for the first time, the function is actually called. If you call it a second time with the same parameter, it does not actually call the function (which could be a very computation-intensive function), but instead uses the cached value from the dict.

If you want to use caching in a real project, I recommend [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Also, there are other cache implementations available in a (non-stdlib) library named [`cachetools`](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/).